# passing json to other vue component

Tags: vue.js

I sent json in sup component to sub component but when I tried to use it like voca[1].e it won't be possible in sub component.

The json is same like this

```
voca: [{"e" :"happy", "k": "행복"},{"e" :"happy", "k": "행복"}, ...]
```

and I sent it to sub component to use a props.

```js
<script>
import sub1 from './components/sub1.vue'
import sub2 from './components/sub2.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    'sub1': sub1,
    'sub2': sub2
  },
  data() {
    return {
      message: '',
      voca: [
        {"e" :"happy", "k": "행복"},
        {"e" :"happy", "k": "행복"},
        {"e" :"happy", "k": "행복"}
        ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
       
      }    
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <sub1 v-bind:propsdata="voca"></sub1>
    <sub2></sub2>
  </div>
</template>
```

this is sub component's code snipet

```js
<script>
export default {
    props: ['propsdata'],
    data() {
      return {
          obj: propsdata
      }  
    },
    computed: {
        
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        sub
        <p>{{obj[0].english}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

like I said obj[0].english is not work 
the error is here

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'english' of undefined"
```

How to use like voca[0].english when I get data from props in sub component?

Comment: Should it not be this.propsdata when assigning it to object

Comment: In the array I can't see a property named english

Comment: Do `obj: this.propsdata ` instead of `obj: propsdata` in your sub comp code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to read an object property that does not exist, that's why you get a *TypeError*

```
{{obj[0].english}} //english does not exist in your array of objects
```

Please take a look to this [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmz2vrz4vv).

Regarding Vue.js props, you are doing correctly via **v-bind**, in the example I provided you, I use the short hand syntax which is colon followed by the property name of the subcomponent you need to pass the prop, i.e:

`<YourAwesomeComponent :myPropName="SomeData" />`

Please take a look to the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Static-and-Dynamic-Props) get more details about props on Vue.js.